# How to notify .net api from WordPress WooCommerce when there is a new order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

I have .net webapi that also integrated with WooCommerce .NET wrapper. Also I have a WordPress store runs on WooCommerce.

What I am trying to do is, as soon as there is a new order on the website, I want to notify my webapi with that order so I can save that order on other application.

I am able to use WooCommerce api to get orders, products etc.. but I want that the WooCommerce api post me the data when there is a sale. Or at least notify me with order id so I can go ahead and get that order with that order id from my .net application.

I have searched a lot but all I find is consuming the WooCommerce api. But I couldn't find anything that WooCommerce notifies my api.

I also checked the web hooks, but I didn't get it. There is a delivery url. From my understanding, for a created action, it hits that delivery url, but what it posts? Json object? I couldn't find any explanation for that. I am kind of new to WooCommerce.

Is this possible? Is there any example for this or any documentation about what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code in your WooCommerce store/setup (theme's functions.php preferable).

```
// add the action 
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'action_woocommerce_new_order', 10, 3 ); 

function action_woocommerce_new_order($order_id){

// Do what ever with the order id, send mail or call your API

}
```

Comment: Make sense. Thanks a lot